# Wrong page ranked for keyword

Tags: seo

The page is in different than en language but I will translate it to be more clear for everyone. The problem is that google is indexing higher my index page for a keyword "garage door" than a page made exactly for garage doors.

Here I will describe the tags and content for both pages:

Index: http://example.com/
Title: Example doors for the home and industry
2 x h1 tags: For the Home; For the industry
2 x h2 tags: garage doors(link to the garage doors page), automation, external doors; industrial doors, reloading systems, automation

Page wanted to be ranked better for keyword "garage doors": http://example.com/garajni.php
Title: Garage doors - Bulgaria - Example
1 x h1 tag: Garage doors
7 x h2 tags: containing all offered types for garage doors
6 x h3 tags: additional highlight for each type of garage door
7 x p tags: under each type of garage doors describing it for the most important details.
img alts: describing perfect the images

I don't get what am I doing wrong that google doesn't want to high rank this page....

Comment: Questions seeking individual SEO advice are considered off-topic here since that's unlikely to help future visitors. It might be helpful to review the following question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google